How to migrate resourceId from Spring Security 2.x.x to 5.7.x?
Earlier we were configuring method coming from ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter, but with new Spring Security 5.7.x, I could not find any option to configure so.
My code:
@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId(resourceIds).tokenServices(tokenServices);
}

I tried looking for docs but its saying resource id is unported feature. As I am aware it will look for resource id when we will make OAuth2 call.
